# Javascript - Focus lost and gain on iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe

When a user clicks outside of the website, a blur gets called, and I capture a focus lost event. When the user clicks then on the website, a focus gets called, and I capture then a focus gain event.

But with an iframe it works a bit different. For an iframe is seen as another website, a "tab". So I have the following listeners:

```
document.addEventListener('blur', function() {
    if (document.activeElement !== document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0]) {
        callback(isVisible(false));
    }
}, false);

document.addEventListener('focus', function() {
    callback(isVisible(true));
}, false);
```

This prevents that when you click on the iframe to cause a focus lost, but when you click outside the website/browser, then no event gets captured, but as soon as you click the parent and then outside then it captures the focus lost event.

So all I need is, when the active element is the iframe and is clicked outside the parent website, that it should capture a focus lost event `isVisible(true)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could find is to check the `hasFocus` on Document every few milliseconds. I chose 700ms.

```
setInterval(t.checkFocus, 700);
checkFocus() {
  if ( document.hasFocus() ) {
    if (!this.inFocus) {
      analytics.focusGained(this);
      this.inFocus = true;
    }
  } else {
    if (this.inFocus) {
      analytics.focusLost(this);
      this.inFocus = false;
    }
  }
}
```